# Would this work to continuously do something?

Tags: java, for-loop

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 2; i++) {
  for (Player p : Bukkit.getOnlinePlayers()) {
    if (i == 1) {
      TitleAPI.sendSubTitle(p, ChatColor.translateAlternateColorCodes('&', "&cTokens &7: &a" + tokens.getTokens(p)));
    }
    if (i == 2) {
      TitleAPI.sendSubTitle(p, ChatColor.translateAlternateColorCodes('&', "&cLevel &7: &a" + levels.getLevel(p)));
      continue;
    }
  }
}
```

the idea is, if the index of the for loop is 1, do the first, if it's 2, then do the second and then start all over again, making the index 1...

Comment: Improved the formatting of the code, and the wording of the question.

Comment: According to your comment below, your real code involves some external piece to handle the "and then start all over again" part. So any answer to this question will be completely irrelevant to what you're actually doing. Voting to close . . .

Answer (score 1):

It would not, because the for loop will end when i reaches 3.

You can do this a lot simpler like this:

```
while (true) {
    for(Player p : Bukkit.getOnlinePlayers()){
        TitleAPI.sendSubTitle(p, ChatColor.translateAlternateColorCodes('&', 
                            "&cTokens &7: &a" + tokens.getTokens(p)));
        TitleAPI.sendSubTitle(p, ChatColor.translateAlternateColorCodes('&', 
                            "&cLevel &7: &a" + levels.getLevel(p)));
    }
}
```

Comment: this would send them both at the same time... What i want to happen is that it sends them at DIFFERENT times. So it does one, then does the other. I have a delayed task outside which i didn't include. It says every 3 seconds do the code.